# Bootstrap glyphicons showing up as empty squares

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Apologies if I'm asking a question that's been answered before -- but I'm brand new to coding and think I need an "explain like I'm five" version.

I've installed Bootstrap, and am trying to put GLYPHICONS into my buttons.

But when I try to put a glyphicon inside a button...it just looks like an empty square.

For example, here's a piece of my code:

Click here to go to Google and <%= link_to "Search", "http://google.com", class: "btn btn-danger btn-lg active glyphicon glyphicon-star" %>

The button shows up exactly how I want it to...except instead of a star next to the word "Search," I just see an empty box.

Any idea why this is happening / how I can fix it?

My GitHub link:
https://github.com/JoshWeisman/pinteresting

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: use the bootstrap cdn..i guess you have not placed the glyp icnos properly... try to add the cdn and let me know if it works

Comment: Hey @Navnit -- thanks for the response. Can you break that down for me? How do I "add the cdn?" (Again, new to coding and I'm kind of an idiot with this stuff still)

Comment: Use CDN this : <link src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome, check the developer tools *console* (press F12 on the page). Mostly it says that it couldn't locate the font files, and you tinker with the CSS file until it finds them. Look for the URL it searches for the font files (but gives not found error), and then fix them in the CSS file.

Comment: surely this is a comment - not an answer

Comment: actually, it is an answer, because it fixes the problem.